Show a column if another column has a specific value in microsoft lists
On my list, when adding a new item, I need the visibility of one column field to be toggled based on value from another column/field (which is a multiselect type of column).
For example column A value can contain "Mercedes, BMW, Porsche). I need column B entry to be visible only if column A contain "BMW". I tried something like below but doesn't work
=if(substring([$Cars],indexOf([$Cars],';#')+2,1000) == 'BMW', 'true', 'false')

Any help?

Is this (Cars) a multiple selection "choice" column or "lookup" column? Multiple selection "choice" columns are not supported in conditional formulas. Let me know if it answers your question.

Yes it's a multiple selection choice column. It's very unfortunate to hear that!

Yes, added detailed answer below with all unsupported column types and documentation link.

Does this mean "lookup" columns are supported? as I tried adding one and directed the formula to it but still the same

Check the documentation link provided in my answer for example based on lookup column.

Unfortunately, SharePoint Online modern experience conditional formulas do not support usage of multiple selection choices columns.
Unsupported column types in conditional formulas:

Person or Group with multiple selections
Choice with multiple selections
Time calculations in Date and Time column
Currency columns
Location columns
Calculated columns
Managed Metadata columns

Microsoft documentation: Unsupported column types in SharePoint conditional formulas

{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "=if(indexOf([$Title], 'BMW' )>=0,'none','block')"

  },
   "txtContent": "@currentField"
}



I suppose this doesn't apply when adding a new item? As it's my main goal

it works on the view when you add an item
